# SQL Server: I am getting an error while altering view when I try to add some virtual column which in turn based on virtual column

Tags: sql-server

I have 20 databases, each with same table but different columns.

So to make the uniform we are creating views on top of each table in a database which will contain all the columns, as there will be one application accessing all the database.

In the view, I have to write the query in such a way that if I want to alter it and add any addition column for testing I should be able to do that.

Now in below query I am altering / creating query such that it takes all the columns of that table from the database, and then I append the other columns which are not present in it.

I need to add a column which will just concatenate some of the columns

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[AIV_PARKING]
AS
    SELECT 
        *,
        Cast(NULL AS [VARCHAR](20)) [ACTCODE],
        Cast(NULL AS [VARCHAR](1)) [ACTIVATEINFO],
        Cast(NULL AS [VARCHAR](20)) [VEHLICNOCHECK],
        Cast(NULL AS [VARCHAR](40)) [ACTIVITY],
        Cast(Isnull(vehlicnocheck, '') + '|' + 
             Isnull(officername, '') + '|' + 
             Isnull(locstreet, '') + '|' + 
             Isnull(locsideofstreet, '') + '|' + 
             Isnull(loccrossstreet1, '') + '|' + 
             Isnull(loccrossstreet2, '') + '|'
              + Isnull(locsuburb, '') + '|'
              + Isnull(locstate, '') + '|'
              + Isnull(locpostalcode, '') + '|'
              + Isnull(loclot, '') + '|'
              + Isnull(locpostalcode, '') + '|'
              + Isnull(Cast(officerid AS VARCHAR(20)), '') 
              + Isnull(officername, '') + '|'
              + Isnull(Cast (issueno AS VARCHAR(100)), '') AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS SearchText
    FROM   
        [dbo].parking
```

Here I added a column called `SearchText` which concatenates other columns, but I get an error

> Invalid column name 'VehLicNoCheck'

Is there any way I can add this column to this view?

I also tried to do to something below but I got the same error:

```
CAST(CASE 
   WHEN NOT EXISTS
   (
       Select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
       Where Column_name ='VehLicNoCheck'
         and table_name='Parking'
   )
   THEN ''
   ELSE ISNULL(VehLicNoCheck,'')
   END as nvarchar(max)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this does not make sense at all.

the [ACTCODE], [ACTIVATEINFO] are all NULL value

so basically SearchText is just a string of '|||||'

you might as well, just do this

```
SELECT  *, 
    CAST( NULL AS varchar) [ACTCODE],
    CAST( NULL AS varchar) [ACTIVATEINFO],
    CAST( NULL AS varchar) [VEHLICNOCHECK], 
    CAST( NULL AS varchar) [ACTIVITY],
    '||||||' as SearchText
FROM [dbo].PARKING
```

Maybe if you can explain what are you trying to achieve here, we can point you to the right direction

EDIT : 
You will need to use Dynamic SQL. You will need a list of all column names

```
-- declare a table variable for all the columns that you required
declare @columns table
(
    id      int identity,
    name        varchar(100)
)

-- for example these are the required columns
insert into @columns 
values ('ACTCODE'), ('ACTIVATEINFO'), ('VEHLICNOCHECK'), ('ACTIVITY')

-- The Query to create the view
declare @sql    nvarchar(max)

select  @sql    = N'CREATE VIEW [AIV_PARKING] AS' + char(13) + 'SELECT' + char(13)

select  @sql    = @sql 
        + case  when t.name is not null 
            then quotename(c.name) + ',' 
            else 'CAST (NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ' + quotename(c.name) + ','
            end
        + char(13)
from    @columns c
    left join sys.columns t     on  c.name  = t.name 
                    and t.object_id = object_id('PARKING')
order by c.id

select  @sql    = @sql
        + case  when t.name is not null 
            then 'ISNULL(' + quotename(c.name) + ', '''')'
            else ''
            end     
        + ' + ''|'''
        + ' + '
from    @columns c
    left join sys.columns t     on  c.name  = t.name 
                    and t.object_id = object_id('PARKING')
order by c.id

select  @sql    = left(@sql, len(@sql) - 8) + ' AS SearchText' + char(13)
        + 'FROM PARKING'

-- print out to view the complete create view statement
print   @sql
-- execute it
exec    sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: But this make it hard coded I have made the package which will automatically create/alter all the view in all 20 databases.So i have to make this generic.On UI we have search Text box where User can type any thing. UI will be same for all the database so search Column should be unique(i.e it should same no. of column).I don't know which column exist in which table at the end each view should contain all the columns for a particular table in all databas

Comment: I want code something like that SELECT  *, 
    CAST( NULL AS varchar) [ACTCODE],
    CAST( NULL AS varchar) [ACTIVATEINFO],
    CAST( NULL AS varchar) [VEHLICNOCHECK], 
    CAST( NULL AS varchar) [ACTIVITY],
   cast(ISNULL(VehLicNoCheck,'') +'|'+IsNull(OfficerName,'')) as nvarchar(max))as SearchText
FROM [dbo].PARKING .So Automatically when i query view it should give me searchText as  |Brian

Comment: Thanks that helped

Answer (score 0):

you could create a view that normalizes the uncommon columns to rows, where the values for the common columns are just repeated, e.g:

```
select id, col, value from parking
unpivot (value for col in (actcode, vehLicNoCheck, etc.)) x
```

the code to dynamically generate the view would be something like:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = 'select id, col, value from parking unpivot (value for col in ('
select @sql += quotename(name) +',' from sys.columns where object_id=object_id('parking') and name not in ('id')
set @sql = substring(@sql, 1, len(@sql) - 1) + '))x'
exec(@sql)
```